# Implementing CKeditor upload adapter CKfinder in Vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have read the docs and dozens f stackoverflow topics about implementing CKeditor with the upload adapter CKfinder. But none are in vue. Only about CKeditor but nothing about the CKfinder. The docs are so unclear to me and I have read some other topics complaining about it too. So I hope someone here can help me to understand how this works.

So this is what I have right now:

```
<template>
    <section class="j-input-text-editor row">
        <label v-if="label" :class="label_class">
            {{label}}
        </label>
        <div :class="input_class">
            <ckeditor ref="editor" :editor="editor" v-model="mValue" @input="updateValue"></ckeditor>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

    export default {
        name: "textEditor",
        data() {
            return {
                mValue: '',
                editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
                editor: ClassicEditor,
            }
        },
        created() {
            ClassicEditor
                .create( this.$refs.editor, {
                    ckfinder: {
                        uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json' // here you can set your own file path
                    }
                } )
                .then(console.log('yeay'))
                .catch(console.log('error'));
        },
    }
</script>
```

So i tried uploading an image in the editor and i get this:
[image]

Like I said. I'm totally stuck at this point and bin trying sins friday (weekend I had not to work obviously)

P.S. am also using laravel, do I need something in the back-end?
P.S.S. My english is not the best, I know. If I need to explain more clear what my problem is then I will try my best to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could install CKeditor. You can download it from: https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/download/

They have a Laravel package as well: https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package

Comment: This answer is not helpful and does not address the issue the OP has.